# .htaccess redirect rules after forum software migration

Tags: regex, .htaccess, xenforo

We're currently upgrading our site forum software, and need to redirect all old forum thread URLs to the new format.

We've tried a couple of things but can't get this to work, as different .htaccess redirect rules are conflicting.

Old format:
https://www.example.com/beta/news-and-announcements/1354-thread-name.html

New format:
https://www.example.com/beta/threads/thread-name.1354/

We would like these to 301 redirect to the new URL structure to ensure everything keeps working.

news-and-announcements in the first URL is a dynamic sub-forum name.
1354 is the thread ID - this is really the only bit that needs to be kept and moved over to the new URL.
thread-name - forum thread name - as long as the ID is in the correct place this will get rewritten to be correct by the new forum software.

This is the default .htaccess mod_rewrite section:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

We've tried to expand this to cover some additional redirects from the old URL structure like this, but it's not working:

```
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*)\/(\d*)-(.*).html$ threads/$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The above redirect doesn't work, and also breaks the AdminCP URLs somehow:

https://www.example.com/beta/admin.php

Any help on getting this working would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

test it!

```
RewriteRule ^news-and-announcements/(\d+)-(.+).html /threads/$2.$1/? [R=301,NC,L]
```

add this codes below *`RewriteEngine On`* on `.htaccess` file